# Clear Contents Only Inside the "Table"

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating templates where data will be imported to. I need code to clear the contents whenever I'm updating.

I don't want to turn it into a **Table** but I want to treat it as a Table, such that I will only clear and update contents in that "Table".

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **Invoice Number** | **Customer** | **Formula 1** | **Formula 2** |  |  | **Date** |
| 2 | 111 | Mary | =A1&B2 (Formula) | =A1&"X" |  |  | January 1 |
| 3 | 112 | Joseph | 112Joseph | 112X |  |  |  |
| 4 | 113 | Anthony | 113Anthony | 113X |  |  |  |
| 5 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 6 | Recording Notes: |  |  |  |  |  |  |

I want every time I update to:

1. Clear all contents from A3 to the Last Cell of the "Table" which in this case, D4
2. Clear contents only in Row 2 keeping keep the formulas in row 2 which I will be dragging down in separate code.

Note: I don't want the contents outside my "table" to be cleared.

```vb
Function GetColumnLetter(ColNum As Long) As String
    Dim vArr
    vArr = Split(Cells(1, ColNum).Address(True,False),"$")
    GetColumnLetter = vArr(0)
End Function


Sub Clear()

    OnError GoTo Done

    Dim r1 as Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastColNum As Long
    Dim LastCol As String

    
'Determine Last Row
    If IsEmpty(Range("A2")) = True Then
        Lastrow = 3
        Else: Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    EndIf 'I think problem is in this If loop but I put this since code acts funky once A2 and the rest are cleared

'Determine Last Column
    LastColNum = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count

    LastCol = GetColumnLetter(LastColNum)

    Set r1 = Range("A3:" & LastCol & Lastrow)

    r1.ClearContents

    Range("A2:" & LastCol & "2").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContent

    MsgBox "Contents Cleared"

Done:
MsgBox "Contents Cleared"

End Sub
```

Works the first time but fails once the table is cleared and I run the code again.
In the first run, contents in row 2 are not cleared.
In the second run, the entire row 2 is cleared, defeating my goal to keep the formulas in row 2.

I can't put a range because the number of rows and columns change in different templates so I rely on Last Column and Last Row variables. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean with *"fails"*: What happens? Nothing? A runtime error? Something wrong?

Comment: Take away the `OnError GoTo Done` (should be `On Error GoTo Done`) so you can see what's going wrong. Also, a small typing error in the question, I suppose: `EndIF` instead of `End If`

Comment: My suggestion is to clear only the cells (columns) that contain the data, not the columns with formulas. You can modify the formula to check `=IF(ISBLANK(A2),"",<put your formula here>)` so that is "looks" like it's been cleared. So your macro would then selectively clear the range A2:B<lastRow>, E2:G<lastRow>, etc. It's also possible that your macro is incorrectly finding the last row/column. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/find-last-used-cell-in-excel-vba/59081657#59081657) for more information.

Comment: Two issues running your code apart from the aforementioned ones: You're going to have two MsgBox's repeating themselves if you don't encounter an error. Since you're clearing contents only, the CurrentRegion remains the same and you'll end up clearing the same region as before (not that that throws an error). You will throw an error with the `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)` returning nothing and thus cannot clear its contents. You can check this by giving it to a range variable and checking if it's `Nothing` and if not -> `.ClearContents`

Comment: This fails for me: `Range("A2:" & LastCol & "2").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContent` with "Object doesn't support this property of method."

Comment: Hi everyone, 

my issues are:

(1) In the first run, Contents in Row 2 are NOT cleared.
(2) In the second run, the entire Row 2 is cleared, defeating my goal to keep the "Formula" cells in Row 2.

Hope this clears my problem. Thank you

Comment: The first time you run through, the `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContent` Fails - row 2 still exists. The second time you run through, the last row **IS 2** and it is cleared by `r1.ClearContents` - Row 2 is now gone. See my answer below, that works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Range for CellTypeConstant is not contiguous. You have to clear each area in the Range separately.

This is bad:

```
    Range("A2:" & LastCol & "2").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContent
```

Do this instead:

```
    '+++ Erase all but the formulas
    Dim rConstants As Range
    Set rConstants = Range("A2:" & LastCol & "2").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    
    ' The Range might not be contiguous.
    ' Clear each area.
    For Each r1 In rConstants.Areas
        r1.ClearContents
    Next r1
    '---
```

Also, do this:

```
    MsgBox "Contents Cleared"
    Exit Sub
    
Done:
    MsgBox "Contents Cleared"
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Nick, your code worked wonders for me. I cannot thank you enough!

Comment: Quick follow up though, as mentioned by Notus Panda above, how come I do get two Msg Box ? Not sure how to fix this...

Comment: After the first MsgBox, do `MsgBox "Contents Cleared"` and then `Exit Sub`. Otherwise you will MsgBox again after the `Done:`

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

If you have not too many rows

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ClearTable()

    Dim cel As Range, lastcol As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ActiveSheet
        lastcol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Set cel = .Range("A3")
        Do While Not IsEmpty(cel)
            cel.Resize(, lastcol).ClearContents
            Set cel = cel.Offset(1)
        Loop
        For Each cel In .Range("A2").Resize(, lastcol)
            If Not cel.HasFormula Then
                cel.ClearContents
            End If
        Next
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Wow this is a much more efficient code. Thanks so much again CDP1802!!

Comment: @ClaireMelindaDunphy Remember to accept as answer if this was the solution :)